# pthread executes after expected

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, ubuntu, posix

I'm trying to compress a file consisting of 1's and 0's as part of an assignment. I have succeeded in doing this, however to get a feel for threads I'm trying to display a simple progress display using a pthread. The problem is that the thread executes AFTER the compression is complete. Here is my program:

```
    void* compressShow(void *)
    {
        pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ENABLE, NULL);
        pthread_setcanceltype(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ASYNCHRONOUS, NULL);

    cout<<"Compressing";

    while(1)
    {
        sleep(1);
        cout<<".";  
        sleep(1);
        cout<<".";
        sleep(1);
        cout<<".";
        sleep(1);
        cout<<".";  
        cout<<"\b\b\b\b";
    }

}

void compression(char *buffer, ofstream &outFile)
{
    //Some Compression code. Function executes each time a new line is lifted off the file. 
}  

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   

    if(argc < 3)
    {
        cout<<"You entered an insufficient number of command line arguments."<<endl;
    }

    else
    {
        ifstream inFile;
        inFile.open(argv[1], ios::in);
        ofstream outFile(argv[2]);

        char buffer[100] = {NULL};

        pthread_t thread;
        pthread_attr_t attribute;

        pthread_attr_init(&attribute);
        pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attribute, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);

        pthread_create(&thread, &attribute, compressShow, (void *)5);

        while(inFile.good())
        {
     `     inFile.getline(buffer, 100, '\n');
           compression(buffer, outFile);
        }

        pthread_cancel(thread);
        //pthread_join(thread, NULL);
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Since I'm creating the thread BEFORE the while loop, I expect it to run concurrently with the loop that is doing the compression.

Comment: Why are you creating the thread detached? You cannot use pthread_join if you create the thread detached by the way: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7990989799/xsh/pthread_attr_setdetachstate.html

Comment: Also, it would be a better way to do the work in the created thread and put the dots to the screen (handle i/o) in main thread (calling pthread_tryjoin_np on the worker thread).

Comment: Because I'm trying to execute it independent of the work being done by main.

Comment: Threads already have independent contexts when created.

Comment: Creating it with default attributes doesn't seem to fix the problem either. I'm just trying to find out why the thread isn't executing in concurrence with the main thread.
After the compression is completed (while loop exits) I see the code from the thread function execute once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with threads.  See the same effect with

```
int main()
{
    compressShow(0);
}
```

Try sending the `flush` manipulator from time to time.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what you mean. :/

Comment: The thread is running fine, but your output is getting buffered because you aren't sending newlines.  Overcome this with, say, `cout << "." << flush;`

Comment: That seemed to fix it. Thank you!
However could you also tell me what flush is doing in this scenario? I've never encountered this issue before.

Comment: Standard output can be line buffered for efficiency.  The implementation stores characters until a newline is seen, then it sends the whole line to the terminal.  Usually, you don't see the effect because you send newlines, or `endl` - which sends a newline and a flush.